# Probability of 2 married couples sitting in a circle

Tags: probability, combinatorics, conditional-probability

I am not able to figure out where I am going wrong. The question is this -

> A total of $2n$ people, consisting of $n$ married couples, are randomly seated (all possible orderings being equally likely) at a round table where men
>   and women are to sit alternately. Let $C_i$ denote the event that the members of couple $i$ are seated next to each other, $i = 1, . . . , n$.
>
> (a) Find $P(C_i)$.
>
> (b) For $j \neq i$, find $P(C_j|C_i)$.

For part (a), my reasoning goes as follows - Pick a man and place him at a particular position. Then, his partner can be choosen in $1$ way and she can be seated in $2$ ways. Then remaining $n-1$ men and $n-1$ women can be seated in $(n-1)!(n-1)!$ ways. The total number of ways of seating $n$ men and $n$ women is $n!(n-1)!$. So, probability is $2/n$.

For part (b), I am starting in same way - Pick a man and place him at a particular position. Then, his partner can be choosen in $1$ way and she can be seated in $2$ ways. Now pick another man, which can be done in $n-1$ ways and his partner, and they can be seated in $n-1$ positions (as there are $n-1$ remaining positions for men and women to sit in alternate positions). Remaining $n-2$ men and $n-2$ women can be seated in $(n-2)!(n-2)!$ ways. So,

$P(C_i\cap C_j) = 2(n-1)^2(n-2)!(n-2)!/(n!(n-1)!) = 2/n$

and $P(C_i) = 2/n$ (from part (a) )

So, $P(C_j|C_i) = P(C_i\cap C_j)/P(C_i) = (2/n)/(2/n) = 1$

I don't understand here where I am going wrong.

Comment: you see arranging n-1 men and n-1 women have (n-2)!(n-1)!.But after that there are 2n-2 gaps for married couple in which they can be put in only one way(so that they sit alternatively).So the answer was right , but method was wrong!

Comment: First of all your interpretation of question in 2nd part is wrong because we have fixed the 2 couples  who need to together (j is a fixed number like i). Secondly if it was  correct then the way you have counted will contain a lot of repeated cases. Let's say first you selected 1st couple , then selected 2nd couple and made them 2 sits right of first couple . Then arranging n-2 couples it is possible 3rd couple sits together and put them 4 seats left of first couple.This is also possible if you selected 3rd couple before 2nd and while arranging n-2 couples made 2nd couple sit together.

Answer (score 1):

(a) Fix one of the partners in the couple. The other one is equally likely to be in any of the remaining $2n-1$ places, of which $2$ are next to the first partner, so $P(C_i)=\frac2{2n-1}$.

(b) If couple $i$ are seated next to each other, that leaves $2n-2$ seats in a row. All selections of two of these seats for couple $j$ are equally likely. There are $\binom{2n-2}2$ such selections, and $2n-3$ of them have adjacent seats, so $P(C_j\mid C_i)=\frac{2n-3}{\binom{2n-2}2}=\frac{2(2n-3)}{(2n-2)(2n-3)}=\frac1{n-1}$.

Comment: Have you accounted for the fact stated in the problem that seating alternates men and women around the table?

Comment: @paw88789: I don't see how that's relevant (unless we have some prior for the gender composition of couples, but none is specified).

Comment: @joriki women need to sit in alternate manner so total available seats are n for a woman.It's not possible that her partner sits seat away from him

Comment: I wondered about that too, but because there were $n$ men and $n$ women (inferred because otherwise the seating can't alternate between men and women); and because of how OP was approaching the problem, I surmised that the couples were each one female, one male. (I know, somewhat old-fashioned!)

Comment: @paw88789: Well, I didn't feel like making old-fashioned (a.k.a. heteronormative) assumptions that the OP may or may not have forgotten to state – I answered the question exactly as posed.

Comment: @joriki Then the math may get tricky.  If there are same-sex couples, they can't sit next to each other because of the condition of females and males alternating around the table.

Comment: @paw88789: It would get tricky if we were given information about the gender composition of the couples. E.g., seating $\frac n2$ heterosexual and $\frac n2$ homosexual couples with men and women alternating would be complicated. But that's not the situation here – we're not given such information, so we should just take the alternation of the genders as an independent fact. The couples are randomly seated, and it so happens that the genders alternate, but that tells us nothing about the adjacency of couples, since we don't have a prior for their gender composition.

Comment: @joriki If we have a same-sex couple, their probability of sitting next to each other is $0$. If we have a female-male couple, their probability of sitting together is $\frac{2}{n}$. Without information on gender composition, I don't see how we can even state the probability of a couple sitting together.

Comment: @paw88789: You're treating the gender alternation as a condition. I think the only consistent way to treat it, absent a prior for the gender composition of the couples, is as an independent fact that happens to be true about the randomly chosen seating arrangement.

Comment: @joriki Yes I agree.  Do you agree that with that being the case, a same-sex couple could not be sitting next to each other?

Comment: @paw88789: I do. (Pun intended :-)

Comment: @joriki You have solved for the case when there is no restriction on seating arrangement. In the question, it is said that men and women have to sit alternately i.e., no 2 men can sit together and no 2 women can sit together. Also, there is no same-sex couple, a couple in this context is male-female pair only.

Comment: @AnkitSeth: Please edit the question to reflect that assumption. The question should be understandable to everyone without having to read comments under the answers.

Comment: @joriki I have edited the question to point out that men and women have to sit alternately. Also, you have to assume that by default, a couple is a man-woman pair unless stated otherwise. Its not given in the question explicitly.

Comment: @AnkitSeth: I find that quite discriminating. Imagine being homosexual and constantly reading problems that assume without even stating it that your kind of relationship doesn't exist. Do you want to contribute to people feeling that way?

Comment: @joriki Its not my intention to hurt anyone's feelings. Its just the way the question is written in the book and the answer matches if you solve considering a pair as I mentioned before. You can take a look at the question yourself (pg 178, Q 67)- http://www.julio.staff.ipb.ac.id/files/2015/02/Ross_8th_ed_English.pdf

Comment: @joriki I just want a solution that gives me the answer that matches in the book (of course assuming that it is correct). If you can get the answer using your assumptions, I will be very happy to accept the answer and also my fault for not considering those assumptions.